# Searching for a pretty chart library with the ability to generate SVG charts, which will be included into a printed report

Tags: charts, svg

I badly need a good looking chart library to generate SVG charts, which will be included in a printed report.

The difficulty is to find such a library, because:

- most of the cool ones have no SVG output ( I don't need interactive SVG for websites)
- most of the cool ones are client-sided javascript ones ( it has to be automatically generate the charts and I don't want to have a web browser running on the server, seems weird )

Basically the features should be:

- **good looking (charts themself & after print)**
- **SVG image output**
- **possible to generate on a server without graphical interface**
- JSON based (not required but would be nice)

I can't believe there is no library out there to fulfill these conditions.

Thanks for any help

Comment: which ones have you ruled out so far?

Comment: At the moment I'm using JPGraph(php), which is not enough because the printed report is a mess. Also JFreeChart is not enough because the charts look shitty. The best would be a JS library like http://www.zingchart.com/ but this is only client-sided. I also found some stuff to bring it on the server with node.js but I think it is more experimental than ready for use. -- I just found pChart, which looks pretty good but I'm not sure if it can produce svg-files.

Comment: and no google chart, because I don't want to send my data to google ;)